Query Table Synonyms and Descriptions in PowerBI
When viewing tables within PowerBI's client Model View on a Semantic Model, selecting an element of a table brings up a Properties panel. Within this panel, Name, Description, and Synonyms are viewable and editable.
Is there a way to pull the all table elements and include their name, description, and synonyms within a semantic model in PowerBI via direct query, DAX, or any other mechanism? I am hoping to use these to create a glossary of elements for my model while reducing manual operations.
